# How to handle AJAX Pop Up inside <Object></Object> tag using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is my Code Inside the  Tag

```
          <a id="wishlistlogin" href="/user/login?destination=%2Fsearch%2Flocations%2Fwidget%3Fparam1%3D55217%26param2%3D1%26param3%3D0%26paramOthers%3D398.07B911S" class="use-ajax login-popup-form" data-dialog-type="modal" dialogclass="popup-dialog-class"><div class="add-to-wishlist">LOGIN TO ADD TO 
                                               <div class="available-at"><p></p><a id="available_copy">Available:  1 Copy</a></div><!-- case request able is false but force show (1) -->

   <div class="callnumber" style="border:0px solid red !important"><p></p><b>Call #: </b>398.07B911S</div>
```

I tried many ways Javascript Executor and AJAX call but I could not click on " LOGIN TO ADD WISHLIST "

My web url " https://preview.queenslibrary.org/search/everything?searchField=*&category=everything&searchFilter= "

and click on first card Quick View Pane at the right side the Widget  " LOGIN TO ADD WISHLIST "

Please any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This element is nested in an iframe, you need to switch to it first (the widgetObj):

[your iframes hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fXP2.png)

Once you locate the iframe you need to switch to it, via:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_locator)
```

Once you are inside the correct frame you can locate the link `By`:

```
By.id("wishlistlogin")
```

Then the element can be interacted with.